# Call a service when controller loads in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJs and I created a service and want to call that service when a particular controller loads.

The code I used for controller is:

```
sampleApp.controller('ProjectAppController', function ($scope, ProjectAppService) {
    ProjectBudgetService.save().then (
        function () {
            $location.url(''); 
        },
        function () { 
            $scope.error = true;
        }
    );
}
```

And the code for service is here:

```
sampleApp.factory('ProjectBudgetService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        save: function () {          
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get('http://lh-cip.ultraserve.net.au/project/budget/?',
                      { headers: { 'Authorization': $.session.get("loginToken") } }
            )
            .success(function (data) {
                if(data.options=="") { 
                    alert("No Budget Option.");
                } 
                else {
                    $q.options.push.apply($q.options, data.options);
                    $q.services.forEach(function(entry){
                        alert(entry);
                    });

                    deferred.resolve(); 
                } 
            })
            .error(function (err) {
                $('#al_msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger"><span>Error! Can\'t Complete Login Process.</span><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></div>'); deferred.reject(); 
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is that this code is not working. I don't know where is the problem. Please help me to sort it out. Thanks

Comment: Check your console, under the Network tab, is the request going through?

Comment: What do you mean with *"this code is not working"*?

Comment: A war of braces is going on. Can you indent the code which will help others help you? :)

Comment: Please consider reading about [this common anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined your service/factory as `ProjectBudgetService` but are injecting in `ProjectAppService`

Seems like just a simple typo, but will prevent your service/factory from being injected into your controller properly. Check your console to see what errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a $watch in the controller, you can call the service when the page associated with the controller is loaded.  Something like this.

```
$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
    ProjectBudgetService.save().then( ... );
});
```

Comment: Not required. Service can be called the way OP is using now.